# Adding annotation to MuPDF android

Tags: android, pdf, mupdf, pdf-reader

I have implemented pdf using MuPDF lib.I am trying to draw over pdf after googling a bit I found `MuPDFCore.addInkAnnotation(int page, PointF[][] arcs)` will add Ink annotation to the pdf. Its crashing when I call `addInkAnnotation` method.
Here is my sample code with which I am trying to see something annotated on Pdf But no luck.

```
PointF[][] p=new PointF[1][1];
PointF [] points=new PointF[2];
points[0]=new PointF(200, 200);
points[1]=new PointF(200, 200);

PointF [] points2=new PointF[2];
points2[0]=new PointF(200, 200);
points2[1]=new PointF(200, 200);

core.addInkAnnotation(2, p);
```

where core is MuPDFCore object.

Error log.

```
02-17 20:22:24.610: W/dalvikvm(25082): JNI WARNING: illegal class name 'android.graphics.PointF' (FindClass)
02-17 20:22:24.610: W/dalvikvm(25082):              (should be formed like 'dalvik/system/DexFile')
02-17 20:22:24.610: W/dalvikvm(25082):              or '[Ldalvik/system/DexFile;' or '[[B')
02-17 20:22:24.610: I/dalvikvm(25082): "main" prio=5 tid=1 NATIVE
02-17 20:22:24.610: I/dalvikvm(25082):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x411af508 self=0x41194208
02-17 20:22:24.610: I/dalvikvm(25082):   | sysTid=25082 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1075171120
02-17 20:22:24.610: I/dalvikvm(25082):   | schedstat=( 2908935486 1958496146 7720 ) utm=232 stm=57 core=1
02-17 20:22:24.626: I/dalvikvm(25082):   #00  pc 00001260  /system/lib/libcorkscrew.so (unwind_backtrace_thread+27)
02-17 20:22:24.626: I/dalvikvm(25082):   #01  pc 0005f944  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmDumpNativeStack(DebugOutputTarget const*, int)+35)
02-17 20:22:24.626: I/dalvikvm(25082):   #02  pc 000537ec  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmDumpThreadEx(DebugOutputTarget const*, Thread*, bool)+303)
02-17 20:22:24.626: I/dalvikvm(25082):   #03  pc 00053886  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmDumpThread(Thread*, bool)+25)
02-17 20:22:24.626: I/dalvikvm(25082):   #04  pc 00038e42  /system/lib/libdvm.so
02-17 20:22:24.626: I/dalvikvm(25082):   #05  pc 00041b3e  /system/lib/libdvm.so
02-17 20:22:24.626: I/dalvikvm(25082):   #06  pc 000252f4  /data/data/com.example.pdf/lib/libmupdf.so (Java_com_artifex_mupdfdemo_MuPDFCore_addInkAnnotationInternal+355)
02-17 20:22:24.626: I/dalvikvm(25082):   #07  pc 0001deb0  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmPlatformInvoke+112)
02-17 20:22:24.626: I/dalvikvm(25082):   #08  pc 0004d102  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallJNIMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+393)
02-17 20:22:24.626: I/dalvikvm(25082):   #09  pc 0004f21c  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmResolveNativeMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+171)
02-17 20:22:24.626: I/dalvikvm(25082):   #10  pc 000272e0  /system/lib/libdvm.so
02-17 20:22:24.626: I/dalvikvm(25082):   #11  pc 0002bbe8  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+180)
02-17 20:22:24.626: I/dalvikvm(25082):   #12  pc 0005fb36  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInvokeMethod(Object*, Method const*, ArrayObject*, ArrayObject*, ClassObject*, bool)+373)
02-17 20:22:24.626: I/dalvikvm(25082):   #13  pc 000670e4  /system/lib/libdvm.so
02-17 20:22:24.626: I/dalvikvm(25082):   #14  pc 000272e0  /system/lib/libdvm.so
02-17 20:22:24.626: I/dalvikvm(25082):   #15  pc 0002bbe8  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+180)
02-17 20:22:24.626: I/dalvikvm(25082):   #16  pc 0005f870  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethodV(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, bool, JValue*, std::__va_list)+271)
02-17 20:22:24.626: I/dalvikvm(25082):   #17  pc 000496f2  /system/lib/libdvm.so
02-17 20:22:24.626: I/dalvikvm(25082):   #18  pc 0004857e  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
02-17 20:22:24.626: I/dalvikvm(25082):   #19  pc 00049696  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::start(char const*, char const*)+389)
02-17 20:22:24.626: I/dalvikvm(25082):   #20  pc 00000dce  /system/bin/app_process
02-17 20:22:24.626: I/dalvikvm(25082):   #21  pc 00017040  /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_init+35)
02-17 20:22:24.626: I/dalvikvm(25082):   at com.artifex.mupdfdemo.MuPDFCore.addInkAnnotationInternal(Native Method)
02-17 20:22:24.626: I/dalvikvm(25082):   at com.artifex.mupdfdemo.MuPDFCore.addInkAnnotation(MuPDFCore.java:296)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that shoul be:

```
PointF[][] p=new PointF[2][];
PointF [] points=new PointF[2];
points[0]=new PointF(200, 200);
points[1]=new PointF(200, 200);

PointF [] points2=new PointF[2];
points2[0]=new PointF(200, 200);
points2[1]=new PointF(200, 200);

p[0] = points;
p[1] = points2;

core.addInkAnnotation(0, p);
```

The first new should specify just the length of the outer array, not also the lengths of the inner array - and it should be length 2, seeing as you are specifying 2 arcs.

You'd neglected to set the outer array elements to be the inner arrays.

The first argument to addInkAnnotation is the page number, so 0 is more likely what you want for testing.

Depending on how you are performing other calls into the library, you may need the addInkAnnotation call to be made via an AsyncTask.

Comment: Thanks :-) Can you please tell me how do I save inkAnnotation on password protected pdf?

Comment: Also calling addInkAnnotation in Async hangs My pdf activity if press back and I get ANR. If I comment core.addInkAnnotation everything works fine any idea? @Paul Gardiner

Comment: MuPDF doesn't yet support saving with password protection. That doesn't mean you cannot save an updated, password-protected pdf, but it does mean the resulting file will no longer be password protected

Comment: I cannot guess why your activity hangs. I can only suggest you try copying the pattern of calls from the released app, as closely as possible.

Comment: I added core.save callback in thread its working fine. I am able to solve ANR problem.

Comment: can you point me to any lib that support writing on password protected pdf?

Comment: I am passing r,g,b values to mupdf.c  I am passing yellow color with 255.0 238.0 0.0 but its rendenring green :-(